# sbt native packager dockerCommands copy

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Searching on the internet, and here, but couldn't find answer that solves my problem.

My problem is I want to create a docker image with some custom sql scripts copied from local file system to the docker image.

Directory structure (a multiple module projects) is

```
my_sbt
    + my_app
        - build.sbt ...
    + database
        - build.sbt 
        + scripts
            - ... several sql scripts ...
```

database/build.sbt contains dockerCommands

```
dockerCommands := Seq(
  Cmd("FROM", "postgres:9.5"),
  Cmd("EXPOSE", "5432"),
  Cmd("COPY", (baseDirectory.value / "database" / "scripts" / "a.sql").toPath.toAbsolutePath.toString, "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/a.sql")
)
```

Image can be created successfully if without COPY Cmd (i.e. `docker run -d --rm -p 5432:5432 <docker image>` starts container, and `docker exec -it <container id> bash` can bash to container and validate processing is up running by `ps -ef` in container bash). However, adding COPY statement to dockerCommands crashes the build process `sbt docker:publishLocal` with error **java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.publishLocalDocker(DockerPlugin.scala:335)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$22.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:119)
    at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$22.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:117)
...
```

Run sbt with **-d** `sbt -d docker:publishLocal` doesn't help as it still throws **Nonzero exit value: 1**, which doesn't help at all.

What is the correct way to refer to the local scripts and copy it to docker image?

Thanks

EDIT:

- Just notice that sbt native packager seems to strip of the leading root path i.e. '/'. Any reason why it does so? And how to prevent leading / from stripping off?

  ```
  [info] Step 3/3 : COPY /path/to/database/scripts/users.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/users.sql
  [error] lstat path/to/database/scripts/users.sql: no such file or directory
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link at https://serverfault.com/questions/666149/docker-copy-issue-no-such-file-or-directory/666154#666154 solves my problem.

Basically the problem comes from docker's indirect way of associating local files to docker container.

1. sbt native packager copies local files to target/docker/stage based on **mappings in Universal** section. For instance, below code snippet copies a.sql to target/docker/stage/opt/docker/scripts under project directory

   ```
   mappings in Universal := {
     (mappings in Universal).value :+
     (file(s"${baseDirectory.value}/scripts/a.sql") -> "scripts/a.sql") 
   }
   ```
2. sbt native packager then copies files located at target/docker/stage/ to docker container based on **dockerCommands**'s `Cmd("COPY", "/opt/docker/scripts/a.sql", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d")`

So `The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; ...` where the context is actually starting from **target/docker/stage/**.